# jQuery .load (or $.ajax) to get and set page title?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So far...

```
$('#container').load(hash + ' #page','', function() { 
    $('#container').fadeIn('fast');
    document.title = $('#title').load(hash + ' #title').text();
    });
```

...doesn't work.
Is there a better/correct way to do this?

FYI: -

- I've added the ID #title the  tag (all pages/it's a PHP template).
- The container is .fade(ed)Out beforehand (less important)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that, at the time you assign to `document.title`, the `$('#title').load(hash + ' #title').text()` might not have finished yet.  Try setting the new `document.title` in the callback of that `.load`.

**UPDATE**

Try:

```
$('#container').load(hash + ' #page','', function() { 
    $('#container').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#title').load(hash + ' #title', '', function(data) {
        document.title = $(this).text();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Nikki, this works great! Thanks for the explanation; the title was initially appearing briefly then disappearing.

I'm wondering if there's a way to make "one call/load", fetching the #page contents and #title text?

I (wishfully) tried the following (not so good): - 
$('#ajax, #title').load(hash + ' #page, #title','', function() { 
document.title = $('#title').text();
$('#ajax').fadeIn('fast'); $('#loading').remove();
});

An extra call won't hurt ;-). Thanks again.

Comment: If you really want to reduce it to a single call (in case you have more portions to retrieve, not just `#title` and `#page`), maybe you can pre-load the page in a hidden `div`, then read from there.

Comment: I settled on adding a 'title' attribute to page main header tags (e.g. <h2 title="News Articles">News</h2>) and reading it from there. Mildly hacky, but decent. Thanks again!

Comment: To anyone interested, I'm using a HTML5 data attribute 'data-title' to the each #page. More here: - http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: No need for a hidden div (which can be unreliable if you there are multiple concurrent requests), just use `jQuery.get()`. In the `success` method, you can wrap the `data` argument with `jQuery()` and use the `find()` method to pull arbitrary elements out of a single response. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 6):

I had the same requirement, to update the title for the page after ajax loads and that's what I used – one request, no need to set special attributes in your HTML:

```
var contentWrap = $('#content-wrap'),
    contentId = '#content';

$.ajax({
  url: hash.replace(/^#!\//, '') + '.html',
  success: function(text) {
    var oldContent = contentWrap.find(contentId),
        newPage = $(text),
        newContent = newPage.find(contentId);

    oldContent.remove();
    contentWrap.append(newContent);
    // Set New Title
    document.title = newPage.filter('title').text();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks gryzzly; I'll definitely have a use for this (e.g. plain XHTML sites and avoiding using the rev attribute).

Comment: Works like a charm. It's very weird that `$(text).find('title')` doesn't return anything, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```html
$('#container').load(hash + ' #page','', function(result) { 
  $('#container').fadeIn('fast');
  document.title = $(result).find('#title').text();
});
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
.**filter**('title').text()

$('#container').load(hash + ' #page','', function(result) { 
$('#container').fadeIn('fast');
document.title = $(result).filter('title').text();
});
```

Comment: This is a *very old* question, written 6 years ago.  It is unlikely that the Original Poster is still having this issue;  Therefore, you should take extra time when crafting an answer that would only be useful to others having a similar issue.  Just posting code with no explanation doesn't make a good answer in this case, especially compared to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

We wanted to have an effect such that when someone visits our website, one should see the individual page's Title but when you move away, you can see "We'll still miss you... :)" using the below code:

```
<!-- Active Navigation Script -->
<script>
    var url = window.location;
    $('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
    $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active');
</script>

<!-- Tab Title change Script -->
<script>
    $(function() {
    // Get page title
    var pageTitle = $("title").text();

    // Change page title on blur
    $(window).blur(function() {
      $("title").text("We'll still miss you... :)");
    });

    // Change page title back on focus
    $(window).focus(function() {
      $("title").text(pageTitle);
    });
});
</script>
```

You can see this in action here: http://www.solutelabs.com