# How to change title of page on .load() with new title of loaded page in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’m confused about the `.load()` and `$.ajax`. I have the following jQuery code in my `index.html`:

```
$('.load_ext').click(function(e) {    
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    parentContainer.append($(document.createElement("div")).load(url + ' #content_to_load').html('<p class="loading">Loading&#8230;</p>').hide().fadeIn('slow'));
})
```

and HTML:

```
<a href="test.html" class="load_ext">test</a>
```

In the example above, I’m loading partial content from the `test.html` (the content of id `#content_to_load`). I also want to grab the title of that `test.html` page and replace the `index.html` title page with that one.

I tried doing something like:

```
var url = $(this).attr("href");
parentContainer.append($(document.createElement("div")).load(url + ' #content_to_load', function() { 
     console.log($(document).attr('title'));
}).html('<p class="loading">Loading&#8230;</p>').hide().fadeIn('slow'));
```

without any luck. It gives me the current page title. How can I replace the title by doing something like:

```
$('title').text(newPageTitle);
```

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Jeff Schafer, @dystroy, and @zeroflagL I managed to solve this problem. Here’s the changed code:

```
var url = $(this).attr("href");
parentContainer.append($(document.createElement("div")).load(url + ' #content_to_load', function(responseText) {
  var title = responseText.match(/<title>([^<]*)/)[1];
  document.title = title;
}).html('<p class="loading">Loading&#8230;</p>').hide().fadeIn('slow'));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115200/jquery-load-or-ajax-to-get-and-set-page-title

Comment: @Dom I tried that but they use a `#title` id to find the title. I want the `<title></title>` of the page.

Comment: `Try setting the new document.title in the callback of that .load.` Selected answer.

Comment: Are you confusing [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload) and [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load) Both are different things. `document.title;` will give you the current title of the page. For this page it would be: **"javascript - How to change title of page on .load() with jQuery - Stack Overflow"** You can change it by doing; document.title = "THIS IS MY NEW TITLE OF THE PAGE";

Comment: `.load()` is the one I have in my code above

Comment: thats a part of ajax function., when you use .load you actually make an ajax request.

Comment: Use a callback function...http://api.jquery.com/load/... it's the same as `complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)`

Comment: .load() usually strips the document `html`, `title` and `head` tags. ref http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @JeffShaver: you are right. That’s why it wasn’t working and everyone kept posting wrong answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the title of the new page through the responseText:

`.load(url + ' #content_to_load', function(responseText) {`

`repsonseText` is literally text, though, the source code of the page. You can use regular expressions, for instance, to extract the title of `test.html`. Then you can change the title with `document.title = newTitle`.

Comment: awesome. I used this with a regular expression from dystroy’s answer. Yeah, I don’t know who’s downvoting like crazy. I gave you +1.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with `load` is that jQuery, when building the DOM fragment, strippes what isn't the body. You can use this to get the title of a distant page :

```
$.get(url, function(html){
    var matches = html.match(/<title>([^<]*)/);
    if (matches.length>0) {
        var title = matches[1];
        document.title = title;
    }
});
```

Note that this won't work if the distant page is from a different origin and doesn't specifically allow cross-domain requests.

Comment: Thank you for not posting the same answer as everyone else. I put this in a comment, but seemed to be ignored.

Comment: @JeffShaver It was a good comment Jeff :).  I deleted my answer after I saw your comment.

Comment: @dystroy Seems like there's been an awful lot of strange downvoting on this answers for this question without comments...
I gave you my +1

Answer (score 1):

try this code to change page title

```
document.title = newPageTitle;
```

hope it helps

Comment: I want to replace the title with the title of the page I’m loading

Comment: @Alex r u able to get the new page title?

Comment: @Alex iBlue is giving you an example of how to use `document.title`. Use this information and apply to your code.

Comment: God!! y a down vote can any one explain please..I received 4 down votes on my answer